# Script downloading DI.FM list works only under Opera

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hello fellow stackoverflow'ers!
Today I was tired of old dead links to my fav internet radio, so I decided to make a downloader for all channels from di.fm. The idea was simple: download the page, get to the menu and parse it. After that create a playlist and make user download it.

So I created a PHP script as an API for my JS script. PHP functions were to download the page (JS cannot really do that), save playlist sent via POST in cookies and to provide it as a file. Cookies are supposed to be a communication channel between JS and PHP (with POST I cannot really make file download itself).

So far so good. Everything works like a charm under Opera. Things are getting complicated in Chrome and Firefox. Chrome reloads the page without a download dialog, Firefox works about the same, just sometimes lets me download the list... that is empty.

Any ideas how to solve it? Here is the code (feel free to use it yourself if you like it):
`http://pastebin.com/dcEzxV9w`

Thanks in advice,

Dracco